# dropping observations

Tags: statistics, command, stata

I'm trying in Stata to reduce my data. I have multiple variables, one called `Industry`.

I would like to delete all Firms which are "Banks". But if I use this command:

```
drop if Branche!="Banks"
```

Stata only shows me the Firms that are Banks.

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: can you explain little more?

Answer (score 1):

```
drop if industry != "Banks"
```

and

```
keep if industry == "Banks"
```

are equivalent. It seems that you have it the wrong way round. You need one of

```
keep if industry != "Banks" 
drop if industry == "Banks"
```

Or `Branche`: your question uses different variable names in different places. You should know which variable you need.

Comment: My fault I only have the variable named "Branche" not Industry. and thanks!

Comment: Hey, I have another question regarding the variable "Branche". I want to form groups for example: I want to build the group "Consumer" which should include the following Branches: "Retail, Food/Beverages, Consumer". Do you know what the right command for this could be? I don't know how to find the right Syntax here ..

Comment: Please post a new question with data example and attempted code.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could drop from firms variable observations that have values that contain the word "Bank":

```
gen bank=regexm(industry,"Bank")
```

You may want more flexibility (e.g., not restricting to capitalization of Bank - allowing data entry typo, requiring blank spaces on either side of word or not requiring blank spaces - again typos). The Stata string functions can help with that as well.

Comment: This command doesn't `drop` anything; it just marks matches of the string named to identify what could be `drop`ped.  Also, you don't `drop` observations from a variable; they are removed from the entire dataset. Obvious points perhaps, but these threads are read by beginners too.